# Can we use sine and cosine graphs for varying temperatures?

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, laplace-transform, trigonometric-integrals

I have been researching for a while looking for what to include more than just deriving the equation of Newton’s law of cooling and a website gave me inspiration by stating what if the temperature of the environment is changing (± C). In conclusion, I wasn’t sure if that person carried out the mathematical process in the right way and the only place I could ask for accurate information is here so please let me know what you think about the mathematical process he went for and if it is right or wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Website: http://calculus7.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/nwtnslawcling1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you refer to the equation
$$y'(t)=\frac{3}{20} \left(55+10 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  }{12}t\right)-y(t)\right)$$ we can integrate it.
$$y(t)=55+C \,e^{-3 t/20}+\frac{15 \left(162 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  }{12}t\right)-90 \pi 
   \cos \left(\frac{\pi  }{12}t\right)\right)}{243+75 \pi ^2}$$
Using the initial condition $y(0)=45$, we have
$$C=\frac{450 \pi }{81+25 \pi ^2}-10$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you think it would be possible to use Taylor series for the sine graph?(excuse me I am not well in math)

Comment: @GeneralMO7. If it was over of short interval ot time,yes. But, what is the problem with the sine ? You have this function available on any pocket calculator. But, if you want an *approximation of the last term, I can provide it to you. Just let me know. By the way, may be you could accept my answer (clicking on the green arrox) in order other users know that is is an acceptable answer. Cheers.

Comment: the problem I am facing right now is then what would I do after finding the sine graph? Do I do the same thing as what the person above did and compare the equations?

Comment: I am a bit lost to be honest because I don’t know what I should do with the sine function.